# $h^{p,q}$ of projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

How can we calculate the Hodge number $h^{p,q}= \dim H^p(\mathbb{P^n},\Omega^q_{\mathbb{P}^n})$ of projective space? Is there a reference for that?

Comment: From cellular homology one knows that $\mathbb P^n$ has only nontrivial cohomology at $H^{2k}$, for $k=0, \cdots, n$. One can show that it is generated by the Fubini-Study metric $[w] \in H^2$. Thus $h^{p,q}= 0$ unless $p=q = 1, \cdots, n$ and $h^{p,p}=1$. I think the calculation can be found in Bott and Tu.

Comment: Thanks, that works! And I wonder if there is a proof from algebraic geometry?

Comment: Here is a proof I've found using Google, using purely algebro-geometric methods: http://www.math.purdue.edu/~dvb/preprints/book-chap17.pdf